# Resource image can be referenced in Xaml but not in code, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, resources

Excuse the novice question, but I am just learning WPF.
I have an image that I've set the build action to be "Resource"

If I set it as the Window Icon in the XAML it works just fine.
like this:

```
Window ... Icon="Images/MyIco.png"
```

But, if I try to set it as the source for an Image, I get an exception the resource is not found:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/MyIco.png"); // This does not work
img.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(uri);
```

What am I doing wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your path is correct, if true, u can try this code to load your image

```
    //tmp is your path
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tmp, UriKind.Relative));
    img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    img.ImageOpened += img_ImageOpened;

    void img_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)sender);                
    }
```

Ex: my path is "/Assets/sizes/background/bg_02.png"

Comment: as you can see, the path is right since it works for Icon="Images/MyIco.png" 
I was trying to understand if there is something wrong with the path string for the Uri: "pack://application:,,,/Images/MyIco.png"